# Default font rasterises very badly with T1 fontenc

Tags: font-encodings, lmodern

After the last *MiKTeX* update (Nov. 22, 2017), I have a problem with the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the output PDF, which I've never had before.

I create an essential document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Title of this article}
\author{John Smith}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This is a random text. It is just to show this problem.

\end{document}
```

And this is what I get:
[image: Image of what I get with fontenc.]

[image: You can notice that the word ‘Title’ looks very pixelated.]

My `.log` file says:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.11.22)  23 NOV 2017 14:25
entering extended mode
**./document.tex
(document.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
No file document.aux.
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 10.
[1

{C:/Users/richy/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(document.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 435 strings out of 493312
 4019 string characters out of 3138898
 53761 words of memory out of 3000000
 4055 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 8671 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,6n,17p,118b,187s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 <C:\Users\richy\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknap
pen\ec\dpi600\ecrm1000.pk> <C:\Users\richy\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\lj
four\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecrm1200.pk> <C:\Users\richy\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\f
onts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecrm1728.pk>
Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 19525 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 71 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

By removing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, the result is normal:

[image: As you can se, the result is normal here.]

Since I need to use that package, I wonder whether the only solution to this is the inclusion of `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

*EDIT: using `XeLaTeX` instead of `pdfLaTeX` gives a normal result.*

Comment: install scalable versions of the fonts, eg cm-unicode package in texlive or miktex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm giong to try it.

Comment: you don't need to change your document, just install the fonts via your package manager and latex should find them in preference to the original bitmap versions.

Comment: The name of the package in miktex is cm-super. But if it worked before the update you must already have it.

Comment: Anyway, after reinstalling MiKTeX and cm-super and cm-unicode, everything works fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it with the addition of

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

This is because `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with Computer Modern uses bitmap fonts, which can end up looking pixelated. Latin Modern doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).